# 2 select query in different array on one json object

Tags: php, mysql, json

How do i encode two arrays that retrieves data from 2 different table in my database and encode it in 1 json response

```
 Here is my php
    $sql = "select * from schedule;";
 $sql1 = "select * from matches;";  
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);


 $response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("n_name"=>$row[1],"start"=>$row[4],"end"=>$row[5],"venue"=>$row[6]));

}

 $data= array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
array_push($data, array("teamone"=>$row[1], "teamtwo"=>$row[2], "s_name"=>$row[10]));
 }



echo json_encode (array("server_response"=>$response, $data));





mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What i want is something like this

```
{
    "server_response": [{
        "n_name": null,
        "start": "2016-11-09 00:00:00",
        "end": "2016-11-16 00:00:00",
        "venue": "aaaaaa",
        "teamone": "aaa",
        "teamtwo": "bbb",
        "s_name": ""
    }]
    }
```

Instead i get something like this

```
{
        "server_response": [{
            "n_name": null,
            "start": "2016-11-09 00:00:00",
            "end": "2016-11-16 00:00:00",
            "venue": "aaaaaa"
        }],
        "0": [{
            "teamone": "aaa",
            "teamtwo": "bbb",
            "s_name": ""
        }]
    }
```

Can someone help me. Thanks!

Comment: have any relation in 2 table?

Comment: Yes they have sir. If they have no relation is it not possible to combine them?

Comment: Possible but not use `JOIN`

Comment: show 2 table all column name

Comment: Ill show the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $response['server_response']["n_name"] = $row[1];
    $response['server_response']["start"] = $row[4];
    $response['server_response']["end"] = $row[5];
    $response['server_response']["venue"] = $row[6];
}


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $response['server_response']["teamone"] = $row[1];
    $response['server_response']["teamtwo"] = $row[2];
    $response['server_response']["s_name"] = $row[10];
}

echo json_encode ($response);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir Razib!

Answer (score 0):

echo json_encode (array("server_response"=>array_merge($response, $data)));

or

echo json_encode (array("server_response"=>$response + $data)); // if you run the risk of same key existing in both arrays

Comment: sir the array merge game me  {"schedule_response":[{"start":"2016-11-10 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-04 00:00:00","venue":"bbbb"},{"teamone":"aaa","teamtwo":"bbb","s_name":""}]}                                                               what i need is {"schedule_response":[{"start":"2016-11-10 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-04 00:00:00","venue":"bbbb"}"teamone":"aaa","teamtwo":"bbb","s_name":""}] thanks by the way :)